# Erro na execução da macro no LibreOffice

Tags: vba, libreoffice

Bom dia.

Estou tentando executar a seguinte macro no LibreOffice Calc:

```
Rem Attribute VBA_ModuleType=VBAModule
Option VBASupport 1
Sub busca_cep()

Range("B3:D3").ClearContents

Set ie = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")

ie.navigate "http://www.buscacep.correios.com.br/sistemas/buscacep/"
ie.Visible = True

Do While ie.busy And ie.readyState <> "READYSTATE_COMPLETE"
DoEvents
Loop

ie.document.getElementsByTagName("input")(0).Value = Cells(3, 1).Value
ie.document.getElementsByClassName("btn2 float-right")(0).Click

Do While ie.busy And ie.readyState <> "READYSTATE_COMPLETE"
DoEvents
Loop

Cells(3, 2) = ie.document.getElementsByTagName("td")(0).innertext
Cells(3, 3) = ie.document.getElementsByTagName("td")(1).innertext
Cells(3, 4) = ie.document.getElementsByTagName("td")(2).innertext

ie.Quit

Range("A3:D3").WrapText = False

End Sub
```

Mas na linha 16:

```
ie.document.getElementsByTagName("input")(0).Value = Cells(3, 1).Value
```

Apresenta a seguinte mensagem de erro:

```
Erro de execução do BASIC.
'1'

Type: com.sun.star.lang.WrappedTargetRuntimeException
Message: [automation bridge] unexpected exception in IUnknownWrapper::invokeGetProperty ! 
Message : 
[automation bridge]Property "getElementsByTagName" is not supported
```

Poderiam me ajudar?

Comment: O suporte ao Microsoft VBA no LibreOffice é limitado. Veja: https://help.libreoffice.org/6.2/pt-BR/text/sbasic/shared/vbasupport.html. É possível traduzir para o LibreOffice Basic?

Answer (score 0):

Quando executo a macro ocorre um erro nessa parte:

`ie.document.getElementsByClassName("btn2 float-right")(0).Click`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]